# Why does each Bitcoin wallet application generate the same new receive address?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, address-generation, ledger-hardware-wallet, sparrow-wallet, bluewallet

I use Sparrow, Ledger Live, BlueWallet and Nunchuk Bitcoin wallets. I was under the impression that new receive addresses are randomly generated. However, I have noticed that each wallet application generates the same new receive address each time.

How are new receive address generated?

Answer (score 4):

Many wallets are HD wallets. This means that keys are created using a process that is both hierarchical and deterministic. Hence H.D. Therefore address generation is deterministic. Meaning that the sequence of addresses is not random, although you cannot tell by inspection of the generated addresses. The address generated is determined by the seed number and the derivation path. Hence, wallets with same seed and derivation path produce the same sequence of addresses.

See [BIP-32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki)

When you install a wallet it will choose a random seed unless you specify one somehow - perhaps using a seed phrase or by otherwise setting the seed number and hence the master private key.

Answer (score 1):

New receive addresses in Bitcoin wallets like Sparrow, Ledger Live, BlueWallet, and Nunchuk are not randomly generated. They are derived deterministically from the wallet's seed using a specific algorithm (like BIP32/BIP44). Each wallet follows a predefined sequence, so given the same seed and derivation path, they will generate the same addresses in the same order.